# Set up nativescript-purchase component

Tags: angular, in-app-purchase, nativescript

I would appreciate any help setting up this plug in:

https://github.com/PeterStaev/nativescript-purchase

I have set up a test product in the google play store console.
My app's package is the same in the console and my app.
I have put installed the plugin and try this code on my home controller:

```
import * as purchase from "nativescript-purchase";

(global as any).purchaseInitPromise = purchase.init(["xydGameCoin"]);

//Then load the products import * as purchase from "nativescript-purchase";
import { Product } from "nativescript-purchase/product";

  public loadProducts() { return new Promise(() => 
    purchase.getProducts().then((products: Array) => {
    products.forEach((product: Product) => {
    console.log(product.productIdentifier);
    console.log(product.localizedTitle);
    console.log(product.priceFormatted);
    });

  });
});
}
```

But this block of code never gets the products from the google play store. The error is that the `getProducts()` method does not exist because `purchase` is undefined.

I am missing something here? do i have to create a file with the google store key or something?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolve this issue by doing some research;  I found this:

This plugin **will NOT work if** you are running the app under the following scenarios:

```
 - In an emulator (generally google services are disabled.)
 - Without signature in a normal phone
 - In a phone that has not enabled google payments on the google play store.
```

**Then how did i make it run?**

Created a release version (--aab) signed and publish it to an alpha version in the play store.

Release it
Install in from the google play tester's page 
Only then the plugin worked fine.